# How can I redirect a domain using nameservers

Tags: domain, redirect

I recently bought a domain. The domain registrar doesn't provide a DNS file to edit. It only allows to edit nameservers. How can I redirect the domain to another url by only editing the nameservers?

Comment: You cannot simply "redirect to a URL" using DNS. The task of DNS is to resolve domain names to IP addresses (in your case). If your domain registrar does not provide (additional) services to add DNS entries, it sucks. Go find a new registrar or find a DNS server to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a service that will provide DNS for you. Then change the nameserver records at your registrar to point to the name servers provided by your DNS provider. Then add suitable records to your DNS.

Comment: thanks.. I have a hosting account at GoDaddy. Can I redirect this domain to godaddy name servers? and then what should be the process?

Comment: I've no idea, I don't use GoDaddy.

Comment: Do you think transferring domain to another service provider will work?